# $(this).hasClass('e.g') not returning

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm working on a script that executes through node and accesses a website's html,
everything else is working perfectly but a small part of the script which organises  and fills an array isn't executing:

```
var j = 0;
var headArr = [];

$('tbody> tr > th').each(function( index ) {
     //^accesses elements from a loaded website^  
    var head = $(this).text().trim();
     //^gets data from inside each 'th' tag^
    headArr[j]= head;
    if(headArr[j]===''){
        headArr[j]=headArr[j-1]+'-';
    }
      //^fills an array with this data, and copies last data if this 'th' empty^
    if($(this).hasClass('rowspan')){
        console.log('if fired');
        for(u=1; u<this.rowspan; u++){
            j++;
            headArr[j]=headArr[j-1]+'-';
            console.log('loop fired');
        }
    }
    //^this block is the issue^
    j++;
});
```

The second 'if' block doesn't fire even if i comment out everything except the console.log, I'm newer to jquery and the `.each` function but from my understanding: `$(this)` should be the current 'th' tag, and in this case `.hasClass` should return true,
[here's the html I'm scraping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9Wbn.png) .
Definitely the 'if' statement.

Any feedback or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.

-Aran

Comment: try debugging your code

Comment: `rowspan` is not your className. That's an `.attr()`.

Comment: With jQuery, it helps to paste the HTML as well, so that DOM traversal can be recreated by people looking at your question.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, mistaking rowspan for a class when it was an attribute, thanks a mil!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"rowspan"` is an attribute, not `class` at the linked image of HTML. You can use `.is()` with attribute selector to get a boolean value

```
if ($(this).is("[rowspan]"))
```

Comment: Sure enough your if condition fired the block, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if($(this).attr('rowspan'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`.hasClass` is used for checking a classname

For checking an attribute like `rowspan`, you need to do

```
var attr = $(this).attr('rowspan');
if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
```

**Reference Documentation:** https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-an-jquery-hasattr/

Hope this will help you.